# Transactions API example dialogflow node-js not responding

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I want to use an example of [dialogflow node js transaction API example](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-transactions-nodejs), but when intent `transaction decision` is not responding. when in my log console firebase function, there is no error, anyone can help me?

[image: example is not responding]

Comment: What does your fulfillment request/response look like? You can view this in the [Console Simulator](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/simulator).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on [troubleshoot for transactions API](https://developers.google.com/assistant/transactions/physical/troubleshooting),

make sure you've made sure that Transactions API is active in actions console in deploy >> directory information >> additional information, and then you must fill the description (full and short) even with example (maybe you can fill with random text), and then fill the privacy policy and terms of services with [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) or random website.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)